# How can I 'join' two metrics in a Prometheus query?

Tags: monitoring, consul, prometheus

I am using the [consul exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/consul_exporter) to ingest the health and status of my services into Prometheus. I'd like to fire alerts when the status of services and nodes in Consul is critical and then use tags extracted from Consul when routing those alerts.

I understand from [this discussion](https://github.com/prometheus/consul_exporter/issues/45) that service tags are likely to be exported as a separate metric, but I'm not sure how to join one series with another so I can leverage the tags with the health status.

For example, the following query:

```
max(consul_health_service_status{status="critical"}) by (service_name, status,node) == 1
```

could return:

```
{node="app-server-02",service_name="app-server",status="critical"} 1
```

but I'd also like 'env' from this series:

```
consul_service_tags{node="app-server-02",service_name="app-server",env="prod"} 1
```

to get joined along node and service_name to pass the following to the Alertmanager as a single series:

```
{node="app-server-02",service_name="app-server",status="critical",env="prod"} 1
```

I could then match 'env' in my routing.

Is there any way to do this? It doesn't look to me like any operations or functions give me the ability to group or join like this. As far as I can see, the tags would already need to be labels on the consul_health_service_status metric.

Comment: There is a good article with visual description of joining vectors in a Prometheus. https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/prometheus-vector-matching/

Answer (score 73):

You can use the argument list of `group_left` to include extra labels from the right operand (parentheses and indents for clarity):

```
(
  max(consul_health_service_status{status="critical"}) 
  by (service_name,status,node) == 1
)
   + on(service_name,node) group_left(env)
(
   0 * consul_service_tags
)
```

The important part here is the operation `+ on(service_name,node) group_left(env)`:

- the `+` is "abused" as a join operator (fine since `0 * consul_service_tags` always has the value 0)
- `group_left(env)` is the modifier that includes the extra label `env` from the right (`consul_service_tags`)

Comment: one improvement could be to force the metric u r joining to not affect urs by doing something like this (addition of a metric forced to be 0): `+ on(service_name,node) group_left(env) (0 *consul_service_tags)`

Comment: @EladAmit - yes, perfect! thanks. I'v changed the post to reflect your improvement.

Comment: `consul_service_tags` is always 1, so instead of the `* 0` and `+`, a simpler way of doing this is more like `(max(consul_health_service_status{status="critical"}) by (service_name,status,node) == 1) * on(service_name,node) group_left(env) consul_service_tags`

Comment: [Good PromQL primer](https://www.section.io/blog/prometheus-querying/) if this is as impenetrable to you as it was to me a few hours ago :joy:

Answer (score 9):

It is a good practice in Prometheus ecosystem to expose additional labels, which can be joined to multiple metrics, via a separate `info`-like metric as explained in [this article](https://www.robustperception.io/exposing-the-software-version-to-prometheus). For example, `consul_service_tags` metric exposes a set of tags, which can be joined to metrics via `(service_name, node)` labels.

The join is usually performed via `on()` and `group_left()` modifiers applied to `*` operation. The `*` doesn't modify values for time series on the left side because `info`-like metrics usually have constant `1` values. The `on()` modifier is used for limiting the labels used for finding matching time series on the left and the right side of `*`. The `group_left()` modifier is used for adding additional labels from time series on the right side of `*`. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) for details.

For example, the following PromQL query adds `env` label from `consul_service_tags` metric to `consul_health_service_status` metric with the same set of `(service_name, node)` labels:

```
consul_health_service_status
  * on(service_name, node) group_left(env)
consul_service_tags
```

Additional [label filters](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) can be added to `consul_health_service_status` if needed. For example, the following query returns only time series with `status="critical"` label:

```
consul_health_service_status{status="critical"}
  * on(service_name, node) group_left(env)
consul_service_tags
```

Comment: Is there any way to add all labels from the right side rather than specifying a list of labels in group_left()?

Comment: Prometheus doesn't provide an ability to select all the labels from the right side of group_left(), but ilthis is possible with VictoriaMetrics via `group_left(*)` syntax. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76661818/how-to-add-namespace-labels-to-pod-labels-in-prometheus

Answer (score 3):

The answer in this question is accurate. I want to also share a clearer explanation on joining two metrics preserving SAME Labels (might not be directly answering the question). In these metrics following label is there.

- name (eg: aaa, bbb, ccc)

I have a metric name `metric_a`, and if this returns no data for some of the labels, I wish to fetch data from `metric_b`. i.e:

- `metric_a` has values for {name="aaa"} and {name="bbb"}
- `metric_b` has values for {name="ccc"}

I want the output to be for all three name labels. The solution is to use `or` in Prometheus.

```
sum by (name) (increase(metric_a[1w]))
or
sum by (name) (increase(metric_b[1w]))
```

The result of this will have values for {name="aaa"}, {name="bbb"} and {name="ccc"}.