# Relabel instance to hostname in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have Prometheus scraping metrics from node exporters on several machines with a config like this:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: node_exporter
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - 1.2.3.4:9100
        - 2.3.4.5:9100
        - 3.4.5.6:9100
```

When viewed in Grafana, these instances are assigned rather meaningless IP addresses; instead, I would prefer to see their hostnames. I think you should be able to relabel the `instance` label to match the hostname of a node, so I tried using relabelling rules like this, to no effect whatsoever:

```yaml
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: ['nodename']
    target_label: 'instance'
```

I can manually relabel every target, but that requires hardcoding every hostname into Prometheus, which is not really nice. I see that the node exporter provides the metric `node_uname_info` that contains the hostname, but how do I extract it from there?

```
node_uname_info{domainname="(none)",machine="x86_64",nodename="myhostname",release="4.13.0-32-generic",sysname="Linux",version="..."} 1
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just came across this problem and the solution is to use a group_left to resolve this problem. You can't relabel with a nonexistent value in the request, you are limited to the different parameters that you gave to Prometheus or those that exists in the module use for the request (gcp,aws...).

So the solution I used is to combine an existing value containing what we want (the `hostnmame`) with a metric from the node exporter. Our answer exist inside the `node_uname_info` metric which contains the `nodename` value.

I used the answer to this post as a model for my request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50357418 .

The solution is this one:

```
node_memory_Active_bytes
  * on(instance) group_left(nodename)
node_uname_info
```

With this, the `node_memory_Active_bytes` metric which contains only `instance` and `job` labels by default, gets an additional `nodename` label that you can use in the description field of Grafana.

Hope that this will help others.

Comment: is it query? where should i use this in prometheus?

Comment: Yes it's a query

Answer (score 20):

This solution stores data at scrape-time with the desired labels, no need for funny PromQL queries or hardcoded hacks.
It does so by replacing the labels for scraped data by regexes with `relabel_configs`.

By default, `instance` is set to `__address__`, [which is `$host:$port`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config).

First attempt: In order to set the `instance` label to `$host`, one can use `relabel_configs` to get rid of the port of your scaping target:

```yaml
  - job_name: 'whatever'
    static_configs:
      - targets: [
            'yourhost.lol:9001'
        ]
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: instance
        regex: '([^:]+)(:[0-9]+)?'
        replacement: '${1}'
```

But the above would also **overwrite** labels you wanted to set e.g. in the `file_sd_configs`:

```yaml
[
    {
        "targets": ['yourhost.lol:9001'],
        "labels": {
            "instance": 'node42'
        }
    }
]
```

**Solution**: If you want to retain these labels, the `relabel_configs` can rewrite the label multiple times be done the following way:

```yaml
  - job_name: 'whatever'
    metrics_path: /metric/rolf
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - rolf_exporter_targets.yml
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [instance]
        target_label: __tmp_instance
        regex: '(.+)'
        replacement: '${1};'
      - source_labels: [__tmp_instance, __address__]
        separator: ''
        target_label: instance
        regex: '([^:;]+)((:[0-9]+)?|;(.*))'
        replacement: '${1}'
```

Doing it like this, the manually-set `instance` in `sd_configs` takes precedence, but if it's not set the port is still stripped away.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's helpful. My target configuration was via IP addresses (`1.2.3.4`), not hostnames (`yourhost.lol`).

Comment: it should work with hostnames and ips, since the replacement regex would split at `:` in both cases.
I would rather argue that the accepted answer with a promql solution doesn't do any relabeling, but keeps all labels intact, just displays the data differently.

Comment: This was helpful. I was trying to use `sourceLabels: ["instance"]` but I should have been using `["__address__"]` when doing relabels for my ServiceMonitor. I guess instance get's added later?

Comment: Doesn't that fail when a manually set `instance` contains a `;`?

Comment: @TheJJ .. that, AFAICS, works in all cases: https://pastebin.com/KyrXmx9s

Comment: wouldn't be simpler  to define another scrape job that just scrapes the hostname (and whatever else you want) from the host?

Answer (score 11):

I found hardcode solution:

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'Prometheus'

scrape_configs:

  - job_name: 'shelby'
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - 10.100.0.01:9100
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        regex: '.*'
        target_label: instance
        replacement: 'shelby'
  
  - job_name: 'camaro'
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - 10.101.0.02:9100
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        regex: '.*'
        target_label: instance
        replacement: 'camaro'
  
  - job_name: 'verona'
    static_configs:
      - targets:
      - 10.101.0.03:9100
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        regex: '.*'
        target_label: instance
        replacement: 'verona'
```

Result:

```
    node_load15{instance="camaro",job="camaro"}    0.16
    node_load15{instance="shelby",job="shelby"}    0.4
    node_load15{instance="verona",job="verona"}    0.07
```

Comment: What if I have many targets in a job, and want a different target_label for each one?

Comment: Impossible. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prometheus-developers/ZX42ASznnbw

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to hardcode it, neither joining two labels is necessary.
You can place all the logic in the `targets` section using some separator - I used `@` and then process it with regex.
Please find below an example from other exporter (blackbox), but same logic applies for `node exporter` as well.
In your case please just include the list items where:

- `target_label: app_ip`
- `target_label: instance`.

```yaml
- job_name: 'blackbox'
    metrics_path: '/probe'
    scrape_interval: 15s
    params:
      module: [ http_2xx ]
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - "1.2.3.4:8080@JupyterHub"
        - "1.2.3.5:9995@Zeppelin"
        - "1.2.3.6:8080@Airflow UI"
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [ __address__ ]
        regex: '(.*)@.*'
        replacement: $1
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [ __address__ ]
        regex: '(.*)@.*'
        replacement: $1
        target_label: app_ip
      - source_labels: [ __address__ ]
        regex: '.*@(.*)'
        replacement: $1
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: '{{ blackbox_exporter_host }}:{{ blackbox_exporter_port }}'
```

Comment: For redis we use targets like described in https://github.com/oliver006/redis_exporter/issues/623. Ex `- targets: ["redis://168.x.x.x:17539","redis://169.x.x.x:17539")` How do we make it work there ?

Answer (score 5):

If you use Prometheus Operator add this section to your ServiceMonitor:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
...
spec:
  endpoints:
  - relabelings:
    - sourceLabels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name]
      targetLabel: instance
```

Answer (score 3):

Another answer is to using some /etc/hosts or local dns (Maybe dnsmasq) or sth like Service Discovery (by Consul or file_sd) and then remove ports like this:

```yaml
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: ['__address__']
    separator:     ':'
    regex:         '(.*):.*'
    target_label:  'instance'
    replacement:   '${1}'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need in order not to display unnecessary information (ports) in targets list. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`group_left` unfortunately is more of a limited workaround than a solution.  I've been trying in vai for a month to find a coherent explanation of `group_left`, and *expressions aren't labels*.  Having to tack an incantation onto every simple expression would be annoying; figuring out how to build more complex PromQL queries  with multiple metrics is another entirely.  It would also be less than friendly to expect any of my users -- especially those completely new to Grafana / PromQL -- to write a complex and inscrutable query every time.

My first stab was something like this:

```yaml
  - job_name: 'node_exporter'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['1.2.3.4:9100']
        labels:
          cluster: 'rkv-image01'
          ceph_role: 'mon'
          instance_node: 'rkv1701'
```

Which is frowned on by upstream as an "antipattern" because apparently there is an expectation that `instance` be the only label whose value is unique across all metrics in the job.  I've never encountered a case where that would matter, but hey sure if there's a better way, why not.  There's the idea that the exporter should be "fixed', but I'm hesitant to go down the rabbit hole of a potentially breaking change to a widely used project.  I'm also loathe to fork it and have to maintain in parallel with upstream, I have neither the time nor the karma.

Next I tried `metrics_relabel_configs` but that doesn't seem to want to copy a label from a different metric, ie. `node_uname_info{nodename}` -> `instance` -- I get a syntax error at startup.

Next I came across something that said that Prom will fill in `instance` with the value of `address` if the collector doesn't supply a value, and indeed for some reason it *seems* as though my scrapes of `node_exporter` aren't getting one.  Which seems odd.  But what I found to actually work is the simple and so blindingly obvious that I didn't think to even try:

```yaml
  - job_name: 'node_exporter'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['1.2.3.4:9100']
        labels:
          cluster: 'rkv-image01'
          ceph_role: 'mon'
          instance: 'rkv1701'
...
```

I.e., simply applying a target label in the scrape config.  I'm working on file-based service discovery from a DB dump that will be able to write these targets out.

It may be a factor that my environment does not have DNS A or PTR records for the nodes in question. Yes, I know, trust me I don't like either but it's out of my control.  But still that shouldn't matter, I dunno why `node_exporter` isn't supplying any `instance` label at all since it does find the hostname for the info metric (where it doesn't do me any good).

```
$ curl http://1.2.3.4:9100/metrics | grep instance
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 80082    0 80082    0     0  4383k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 4600k

$ curl http://1.2.3.4:9100/metrics | grep rkv1701
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 80085    0 80085    0  node_uname_info{domainname="(none)",machine="x86_64",nodename="rkv1701.myco.com",release="4.17.13-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64",sysname="Linux",version="#1 SMP Mon Aug 6 14:16:00 EDT 2018"} 1
   0  9268k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 9776k
$
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a relabel rule like this one in your prometheus job desription:

```
- job_name: node-exporter
....
relabel_configs:
  .....
  # relable the label 'instance' with your pod_node_name 
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name]
    target_label: instance
```

In the prometheus Service Discovery you can first check the correct name of your label. The label will end with '....pod_node_name'

Answer (score 1):

Additional config for this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64623786/2043385

```yaml
  - job_name: 'node-exporter'
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoints_name]
        regex: 'node-exporter'
        action: keep
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name]
        action: replace
        target_label: node
```

And my service:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: node-exporter
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: exporter
    app.kubernetes.io/name: node-exporter
  ports:
    - name: node-exporter
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9100
      targetPort: 9100
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody yet provided a correct answer to the initial question.

It's not possible to use `nodename` for relabeling `instance`: https://groups.google.com/g/prometheus-developers/c/ZX42ASznnbw

> Relabelling can only access metadata of the target, metric relabelling can only access the labels of the same metric.

A more detail explanation is here: https://www.robustperception.io/why-cant-i-use-the-nodename-of-a-machine-as-the-instance-label/

> The machine knows its own name, couldn't Prometheus use it?
>
> This is a not uncommon question about Prometheus and service
> discovery. If you run uname -n you'll see a machine's nodename, and
> this is something that'd be useful to have as part of your instance
> label. The node exporter even exposes it as the nodename label on the
> node_uname_info metric!
>
> This is not something that Prometheus can do. The reason is that the
> target labels are determined by service discovery and relabelling,
> before Prometheus ever attempts to talk to a scrape target. You could
> in principle have the scrape target attach it as a label on every
> sample, but that goes against the top-down strategy that Prometheus
> uses for configuration management. Put another way, a target doesn't
> know how a scraper views it. For example the database team,
> application team, and infrastructure teams may all have different
> views on where a target belongs in their label taxonomy. One person's
> primary database is another's 4th machine in the 7th rack in the Irish
> datacenter.

The workaround, but not a solution (!) is to use DNS name for the target instead of the IP and keep the hostname consistent with your DNS infrastructure.

Another way is just to hardcode labels for a target:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: node_exporter
    static_configs:
      - targets:[1.2.3.4:9100]
        labels:
          instance: myhost1.org
      - targets:[2.3.4.5:9100]
        labels:
          instance: myhost2.org
```

Comment: this is not even a workaround and it only works with static sd. The initial question is how to extract a label from the metric itself. https://grafana.com/blog/2022/03/21/how-relabeling-in-prometheus-works/ makes it look like its possible, but does not describe how to address this my_custom_counter_total{server="webserver01 example

Answer (score 0):

Using `bitnamicharts/kube-prometheus` Helm charts, the values.yaml needs:

```
node-exporter:
  serviceMonitor:
    relabelings:
      - sourceLabels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name]
        targetLabel: instance
```