# AlertManager -- Container alert not returning hostname where it is running

Tags: docker, prometheus, cadvisor, prometheus-alertmanager

I am facing one issue, I am using below rule in alert_rules.yml
when I receive alert, it does not returns hostname where the container is running. How can I achieve to return hostname instead of node ID ?

I tried with container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_name instead of container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_id but does not works.

Any suggestions ?

```
- alert: task_high_memory_usage_1g
expr: sum(container_memory_rss{container_label_com_docker_swarm_task_name=~".+"})
  BY (container_label_com_docker_swarm_task_name, container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_id) > 1e+09
for: 1m
labels:
  severity: warning
annotations:
  description: '{{ $labels.container_label_com_docker_swarm_task_name }} on ''{{
    $labels.container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_id }}'' memory usage is {{ humanize
    $value}}.'
  summary: Memory alert for Swarm task '{{ $labels.container_label_com_docker_swarm_task_name
    }}' on '{{ $labels.container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_id }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

No experience with Docker, but if your `container_memory_rss` metrics have both a `container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_id` and a `container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_name` label, then replacing all occurrences of one with the other in your alert rule (including the rule and description/summary) should work just fine. If the `..._name` label is not there, then that may explain why it's not working.

Comment: container_memory_rss does not contains container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_name.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't aggregate metrics by something that isn't there. You might be able to join with some other metric that has both the `container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_id` and `container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_name` labels, something along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50357418/8657904

Comment: But the problem is that `container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_id` is available in cadvisor metrics and `container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_name` is available in node advisor metrics .. how can I join them to use in my case?

Comment: Well, identify a set of labels (or at least label values) that uniquely match your cadvisor metric (`container_memory_rss`) and some node advisor metric that has the `container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_name`label, do any `label_replace` operations needed to match both label names and values (for the labels you identified above), then apply the solution above to join them.

Comment: Do you have any example to to use label_replace operations ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try **$labels.instance**. It will return the instance name where alert is being fired.

Comment: **$label.instance** returns the IP address which is randomly assigned by Docker to its containers.
What I need is the hostname of node, where that container is running.