# PromQL. How to add label value from different metric

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

If I have two metrics:

```
kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total {..., pod="my_pod_name_42", ...}
```

and

```
container_memory_usage_bytes {..., pod_name="my_pod_name_42", cluster_name="megatron", ...}
```

And I want to set up alert for restart metrics, but containing `cluster_name` label. 
Can I somehow aggregate label value from different metrics.

For example alert:

```
increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="42"}[1h])>4
```

need to somehow add `megatron` here ^, for alertmanager to be able to use this label when sending notification

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [label_replace()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function in order to convert `pod_name` label into `pod` label before using `group_left`:

```
(increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="42"}[1h]) > 4)
+ on (pod) group_left(cluster_name)
(0 * label_replace(
  container_memory_usage_bytes{namespace="42"},
  "pod", "$1", "pod_name", "(.+)"
))
```

As you can see the `label_replace()` function isn't trivial to use for labels' renaming. The better approach is to use [label_move()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_move) function from [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html). Then the `label_replace(container_memory_usage_bytes{namespace="42"}, "pod", "$1", "pod_name", "(.+)")` is substituted with more clear `label_move(container_memory_usage_bytes{namespace="42"}, "pod_name", "pod")`

Answer (score -1):

Possible duplicate of [How can I 'join' two metrics in a Prometheus query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461801/how-can-i-join-two-metrics-in-a-prometheus-query) .

One improvement could be to force the metric you are joining to not affect yours by doing something like this (addition of a metric forced to be 0):

```
(
  max(consul_health_service_status{status="critical"}) 
  by (service_name,status,node) == 1
)
   + on(service_name,node) group_left(env)
(
   0 * consul_service_tags
)
```

Comment: But OP's issue is that the matching label in the two time series is named `pod` in one and `pod_name` in the other. That's why the automagic matching with the usual operators fails.