# AlertManager downtime alert unless 429 (To Many Requests) HTTP status code

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Currently I have an AlertManager config that simply sends an alert when the "`probe_success`" metric is 0.

I don't know how I could join the "`probe_http_status_code`" metric with the "`probe_success`" metric in the "`expr`" field of an alert rule to keep the alert from firing when the "`probe_success`" metric is 0 because of a 429 (To Many Requests) HTTP status code.

I tried to figure this out using the similar question below, but no luck.
[How can I 'join' two metrics in a Prometheus query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461801/how-can-i-join-two-metrics-in-a-prometheus-query)

"`probe_success`" and "`probe_http_status_code`" are both Blackbox Exporter metrics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want here is [valid_status_codes](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md#http_probe), so you can specify 429 (plus whatever 2xx codes are expected) as valid which will keep `probe_success` as 1 when they happen.

Comment: I thought about this and it's a proper solution, but I don't think that it's the responsibility of Prometheus/the exporter to decide whether (in this case) a status code is vaid or not. I'd think that it's the AlertManager that is responsible for that decision and whether to alert on it or not. What are your thoughts?

Comment: That's not the Alertmanager's role at all, alerts are already firing when they get to it. The blackbox exporter has many options to determine what is considered failure, and this is one case for it.

Comment: AlertManager was a mistake, I meant the alert rules in Prometheus. Deciding what a failure is for a probe and what not is indeed the responsibility of the Blackbox Exporter, not the alert conditions in Prometheus. Thanks!