# How to merge labels of two Prometheus queries?

Tags: join, merge, label, prometheus

I have two different Prometheus queries :

**Input**

```json
product_description{id="1", quantity="12"} 2
product_status{id="1", status="online"} 1
```

**Desired outupt**

```json
{id="1", quantity="12", status="online"} 2
```

What is the Prometheus query to obtain the equivalent of a MySQL join, to merge the labels of the two queries on the `id` label ?

***Edit***

Thanks to @MichaelDoubez

```
product_description{id="1"} + on(id) group_left(status) (0 * product_status{id="1"})
```

Comment: Those are not metrics: you are missing the value and the value is hidden in a label. Do you mean `product_quantity{id="1"} 12` and `product_status{id="1"} 1` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I 'join' two metrics in a Prometheus query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461801/how-can-i-join-two-metrics-in-a-prometheus-query)

Comment: @MichaelDoubez Indeed, I edited it. And the link you provided solved my problem. I overlooked it the first time I saw it and couldn't get it working at the time. But now it's all good, thanks !