# left join prometheus metrics in grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm using prometheus in grafana to track smart data for drives in a couple servers.   I'm trying to create a table that shows me which drives have >0 reallocated sectors... here are the queries i use:
[image]

```
sum(smartmon_reallocated_sector_ct_raw_value>0) by (disk)

sum(smartmon_device_info) by (device_model, disk, model_family, serial_number)
```

This results in a table like the following:
[image]

I'm using an outer join in grafana to merge the two queries by disk, but the problem is that the table ends up showing all drives, not just the ones with >0 reallocated sectors (currently only /dev/da8).   Grafana doesn't yet have a left join option, only outer join, so I'm not sure if this is even possible...is it?

Answer (score 3):

I think I solved it, with help from:

https://www.section.io/blog/prometheus-querying/

and

[How can I 'join' two metrics in a Prometheus query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461801/how-can-i-join-two-metrics-in-a-prometheus-query)

```
(sum(smartmon_reallocated_sector_ct_raw_value) by (disk) >0) * on(disk) group_right(device_model)  sum(smartmon_device_info) by (device_model, disk, model_family, serial_number)
```

seems to do a right join, resulting in just a single row (for now)

[image]