# How to combine two Prometheus values

Tags: prometheus

I want to show the display name from

```
windows_process_info{ hob = "job" , group = "group" , instance = "instance" }
```

to

```
sum ( windows_process_cpu_time_total { job = "job", group = "group", instance = "instance", process! = "Idle" } ) by ( process_id )
```

How can I combine the two Prometheus queries?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50357418/11344502)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
( sum by ( process_id , process ) ( windows_process_cpu_time_total{ job = "job" , group = "group" , instance = "instance" , process != "Idle" } ) ) + on( process_id ) group_right() ( windows_service_info{ job = "job" , group = "group" , instance = "instance" } )
```

Thanks for the hints.