# How to Join two series in Prometheous using operator +

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Technically, Prometheus doesn’t have the concept of joining series like SQL, for example, has. However, series can be combined in Prometheus by using an operator on them

Series A

```
sum(rate(rpc_request_duration_seconds_bucket{instance=~"10.43.1.244"}[1m]))
```

Series B

```
sum(rate(rpc_request_duration_seconds_bucket{instance=~"10.43.1.245"}[1m]))
```

What is the best way to Join these two series uning prometheous

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I 'join' two metrics in a Prometheus query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461801/how-can-i-join-two-metrics-in-a-prometheus-query)

Answer (score 1):

These are the same metrics. Why would you use join? You can use aggregation `sum` like you did and filter using regex.

Something like this (I didn't test the regex)

```
sum(rate(rpc_request_duration_seconds_bucket{instance=~"10\.43\.1\.24[45]"}[1m]))
```