# how to add label to table from Prometheus SNMP exporter using 2 values from another table

Tags: prometheus, snmp

I am using SNMP exporter to provide metrics from an APC lab monitoring device (using PowerNet MIB).

The relevant part of the Prometheus configuration looks as follows:

```yaml
  - job_name: labtemp_snmp
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - 10.163.123.87
    scrape_interval: 15s
    metrics_path: /snmp
    params:
      module: [labtemp]
    relabel_configs:
     - source_labels: [__address__]
       target_label: __param_target
     - source_labels: [__param_target]
       target_label: instance
     - target_label: __address__
       replacement: 127.0.0.1:9116
```

The Prometheus SNMP exporter configuration was generated using:

```
modules:
  labtemp:
    walk:
      - memSensorsStatusTable
    version: 1
```

When querying by hand ('http://localhost:9116/snmp?target=10.163.123.87&module=labtemp'), the output contains these tables:

```
# HELP memSensorsStatusSensorLocation The location of the sensor. - 1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.10.4.2.3.1.4
# TYPE memSensorsStatusSensorLocation gauge
memSensorsStatusSensorLocation{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="0",memSensorsStatusSensorLocation="Cold Aisle C1",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="1"} 1
memSensorsStatusSensorLocation{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="0",memSensorsStatusSensorLocation="Hot Aisle C2",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="2"} 1
memSensorsStatusSensorLocation{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="1",memSensorsStatusSensorLocation="Cold Aisle C12",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="2"} 1
memSensorsStatusSensorLocation{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="1",memSensorsStatusSensorLocation="Hot Aisle B8",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="1"} 1
memSensorsStatusSensorLocation{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="2",memSensorsStatusSensorLocation="Cold Aisle A5",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="1"} 1
memSensorsStatusSensorLocation{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="2",memSensorsStatusSensorLocation="Hot Aisle B2",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="2"} 1
memSensorsStatusSensorLocation{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="3",memSensorsStatusSensorLocation="Cold Aisle C9",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="3"} 1
memSensorsStatusSensorLocation{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="3",memSensorsStatusSensorLocation="Hot Aisle C12",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="6"} 1
memSensorsStatusSensorLocation{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="3",memSensorsStatusSensorLocation="Hot Aisle C7",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="5"} 1
# HELP memSensorsTemperature The sensor's current temperature reading - 1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.10.4.2.3.1.5
# TYPE memSensorsTemperature gauge
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="0",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="1"} 26
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="0",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="2"} 33
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="1",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="1"} 30
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="1",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="2"} 20
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="2",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="1"} 22
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="2",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="2"} 30
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="3",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="3"} 20
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="3",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="5"} 31
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="3",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="6"} 29
```

Now, I'd like to assign the `memSensorsStatusSensorLocation` values to the `memSensorsTemperature` table using the `memSensorsStatusSensorLocation` table, similarly how this is done e.g. with network interface indexes, so that the entries look like this:

```
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsStatusSensorLocation="Cold Aisle C1",memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="0",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="1"} 26
...
```

For the record, the relevant part of the MIB looks like this:

```
memSensorsStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
   SYNTAX SEQUENCE OF MemSensorsStatusEntry
   ACCESS not-accessible
   STATUS mandatory
   DESCRIPTION
       "Allows for getting sensor status information."
   ::= { memSensors 3 }
   
memSensorsStatusEntry OBJECT-TYPE
   SYNTAX MemSensorsStatusEntry
   ACCESS not-accessible
   STATUS mandatory
   DESCRIPTION
      "The unit to get data from."
   INDEX { memSensorsStatusModuleNumber, memSensorsStatusSensorNumber }
   ::= { memSensorsStatusTable 1 }
```

Clearly, the 2 numbers serve as an index.

There is also another table `memSensorsConfigTable` that contains `memSensorsLocation`:

```
PowerNet-MIB::memSensorsLocation.0.1 = STRING: "Cold Aisle C1"
PowerNet-MIB::memSensorsLocation.0.2 = STRING: "Hot Aisle C2"
PowerNet-MIB::memSensorsLocation.1.1 = STRING: "Hot Aisle B8"
PowerNet-MIB::memSensorsLocation.1.2 = STRING: "Cold Aisle C12"
PowerNet-MIB::memSensorsLocation.2.1 = STRING: "Cold Aisle A5"
PowerNet-MIB::memSensorsLocation.2.2 = STRING: "Hot Aisle B2"
PowerNet-MIB::memSensorsLocation.3.3 = STRING: "Cold Aisle C9"
PowerNet-MIB::memSensorsLocation.3.5 = STRING: "Hot Aisle C7"
PowerNet-MIB::memSensorsLocation.3.6 = STRING: "Hot Aisle C12"
```

Anyone can provide a way/hint how to achieve this ?

It is not clear to me whether this should/could be done in Prometheus SNMP exporter configuration or Prometheus configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand this question fully, even with your own answer. But wouldn't ["joining" metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461801) do what you want here?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `memSensorsConfigTable` and perform double-index lookup. The `generator` configuration looks like this:

```
modules:
  labtemp:
    walk:
      - memSensorsStatusTable
      - memSensorsConfigTable
    version: 1
    timeout: 60s
    lookups:
      - source_indexes: [memSensorsStatusModuleNumber, memSensorsStatusSensorNumber]
        lookup: memSensorsLocation
```

With that, the manual query contains the extra label:

```
# HELP memSensorsTemperature The sensor's current temperature reading - 1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.10.4.2.3.1.5
# TYPE memSensorsTemperature gauge
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsLocation="Cold Aisle A5",memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="2",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="1"} 22
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsLocation="Cold Aisle C1",memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="0",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="1"} 26
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsLocation="Cold Aisle C12",memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="1",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="2"} 20
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsLocation="Cold Aisle C9",memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="3",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="3"} 20
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsLocation="Hot Aisle B2",memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="2",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="2"} 30
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsLocation="Hot Aisle B8",memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="1",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="1"} 30
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsLocation="Hot Aisle C12",memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="3",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="6"} 29
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsLocation="Hot Aisle C2",memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="0",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="2"} 33
memSensorsTemperature{memSensorsLocation="Hot Aisle C7",memSensorsStatusModuleNumber="3",memSensorsStatusSensorNumber="5"} 31
```

The trouble is that the additional table causes the SNMP scraping to take much longer than previously (than just with the `memSensorsStatusTable`). Hence, the timeout had to be raised, as well as scraping interval in Prometheus configuration:

```yaml
  - job_name: labtemp_snmp
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - 10.163.123.87
    scrape_interval: 60s
    scrape_timeout: 60s
    metrics_path: /snmp
    params:
      module: [labtemp]
    relabel_configs:
     - source_labels: [__address__]
       target_label: __param_target
     - source_labels: [__param_target]
       target_label: instance
     - target_label: __address__
       replacement: 127.0.0.1:9116
```