# PromQL join two metrics with identic label names but different label values

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have following PromQL metric structures

```
metric1{label_1="a",label_2="b",...,status="running"} value = 0
metric1{label_1="a",label_2="b",...,status="running"} value = 1
metric2{label_1="a",label_2="b",...,status="healthy"} value = 0
metric2{label_1="a",label_2="b",...,status="healthy"} value = 1
```

I want to select only metrics with specific value and merge these metrics into this structure

```
resultmetric{label_1="a",label_2="b",...,metric1_status="running", metric2_status="healthy"}
```

What is the correct PromQL query? I tried queries with `group_left()` and `on()` but no luck.

Comment: How to rename label: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace, 
How to join metrics: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44461801

Answer (score 2):

The main roadblock you are probably hitting is the fact that the in both metrics you have the `status` label which is different AND the one you want to replicate. Prometheus won't be able resolve it while the label names collide.

The first thing you want to do is generate a new timeseries with a different label name for the second `status`. You can do this by using [`label_replace`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace). For example:

```
label_replace(metric2{...}, "metric2_status", "$1", "status", "(.*)")
```

This will keep the `status` label but will also add a `metric2_status` with the value of the `status` label.

Now you can proceed to use `on()` and `group_left()`. These need to be used with an arithmetic or group function. If you are using this to add more labels to metric1, remember to use an arithmetic that will not alter the metric value.

For example - assuming metric2 has always a value of 1 - this is what you could use:

```
metric1{label_1="a", ...} * 
    on (label_a, label_b) 
    group_left(metric2_status)
label_replace(metric2{...}, "metric2_status", "$1", "status", "(.*)")
```

the resulting metric should have `metric1`'s labels plus the `metric2_status` label.

Answer (score 0):

When using group modifiers such as

```
ignoring()
on()
group_left()
group_right()
```

the label(s) used in `on()` modifier **must** be unique at least in one vector.

Consider `metric1`, `metric2` vectors and common `label_a=...` label used in `on()`. These cases may occur

If `metric1` has unique `label_a=...` and metric2 has unique `label_a=...` we have *one-to-one* match.

If `metric1` has duplicate `label_a=...` and metric2 has unique `label_a=...` we have *many-to-one* match.

If `metric1` has unique `label_a=...` and metric2 has duplicate `label_a=...` we have *one-to-many* match.

If `metric1` has duplicate `label_a=...` and metric2 has duplicate `label_a=...` we have *many-to-many* match and vectors are **not joinable**.

**Additionally** the result vector must have unique set of label keys. That's why we are renaming the label in the right-hand side vector and joining it as a label with different name.

Working query is

```
( metric1{...} == 1 ) *
    on(label_a)
    group_left(metric2_status)
label_replace((metric2{...} == 1), "metric2_status", "$1", "status", "(.*)")
```

`( metric1{...} == 1 )`

Filter `metric1` so that the left-hand side of the query contains only data with **unique** `label_a=...`.

`on(label_a)`

join two metrics on `label_a=...`.

`group_left(metric2_status)`

add `metric2_status` label from right-hand `metric2`.

`label_replace((metric2{...} == 1), "metric2_status", "$1", "status", "(.*)")`

create new label `metric2_status` in `metrics2` from the `status` label.